# sourcing a Bash script - Return on Error, instead of Exit?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm **sourcing a bash script in the terminal**, so exiting on error with

```
set -o errexit
```

kills my terminal, which is EXTREMELY ANNOYING, because I have to close the terminal, open another one, and reset some variables.

So far, using

```
command || return
```

lines, in the script, is doing exactly what I want

```
set -o errexit
```

to do... But I want it done for the entire script; not just one line/command

I have a file full of commands for setting up a site, and I'd rather not do command || return

for every single line in the file

**Is there another set option, or something else that will just "return" instead of exiting the terminal?**

-- **Just for clarity**, I'd like to kill the script, and leave the terminal in the same state that pressing ctrl+C to kill a service running in the terminal would. `command || return` does that. But I don't want to tack on `|| return` to every line in the file. So I'm looking for something  similar to `set -o errexit`, that doesn't cause the terminal to shut down

**--- Note:** 
Creating a dumb script with two lines in it (super.sh):

```
create_path=~/Desktop/site_builder/create.sh
source $create_path blah
```

And placing `set -o errexit` at the top of create.sh,

works exactly as I expect it. However, it's really stupid to have to create a file with two lines in it, just to call another bash script, instead of just calling it from the terminal. Ugghhh

here's some examples:

in super.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

create_path=~/Desktop/site_builder/create.sh
source $create_path blah
```

in create.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
#line below this is a line that fails and will cause the script to stop and return to the terminal as expected 
sed "s/@@SITE_NAME@@/$dirname" 
~/Desktop/site_builder/template_files/base.html > ~/Desktop/$dirname/templates/base.html # a line with a stupid error
```

in the terminal:

```
 $ bash super.sh
```

output as expected:

```
my-mac$
```

This works. What an annoying solution.

I **want** , ideally, to execute what's in the stupid super.sh file from the terminal, not the super.sh file :D, without having the terminal shut down on me. This is what happens with what I'm trying to do:

terminal command:

```
my-mac$ source $create_path blah
```

in create.sh I still have `set -o errexit`

Here's the output on the terminal

```
    sed: 1: "s/@@SITE_NAME@@/blah": unterminated substitute in regular expression
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And then the terminal is frozen. Ctrl+C doesn't work, neither does Ctrl+D

If instead of `set -o errexit` , if I just use `command || return` statements everywhere in the create.sh file, then I get exactly what I want , while executing the lines in supser.sh directly on the terminal (instead of calling super.sh from the terminal). But that's not a practical solution either.

**Note:** I liked @terdon 's answer about just spawning a child shell 
so I ended up just spawning a sub shell via the script instead of the terminal, as he showed in his answer using the braces `( )`, around the entire script.. His answer works too.

Comment: Are you doing this in a script or manually ?

Comment: I'm calling the file with source in the terminal. As in : `source $file_path argument` The script is being executed in the same shell I called it from (what `source` does, I've been told...and acts like that's the case) `command || return` statements are in the file I'm executing in the terminal

Comment: OK, and where is the set run? Is that in the sourced script or do you run it manually? This would be much easier to answer if you could add a simple example we can copy and try out. I have an idea, but I need a way of testing to be sure it works.

Comment: I added a Note to the original post that might help with that.  But I'll also do as you suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the only thing that works for what I needed to accomplish (creating a virtual environment then activating it, then installing requirements from a bash script):

spawn a subshell / child shell from the script, as in:

stupid_file.sh

```
(
set -o errexit
#bunch of commands
#one line fails
)
```

run the stupid_file using:

```
source stupid_file.sh <file arguments here> || true
```

THE END.

** takes a bow **

(credit goes to Jeff and Terdon)

Comment: This isn't really any different than just executing the script instead of sourcing it.

Comment: @chepner hmmm. Cool. I'll have to try calling just `bash $create_path blah` and see if it still exits, and executes the same way, and still installs stuff into my virtual environment correctly. Out of time now.

Comment: I'll save you the time: it won't (if by "installs stuff" you means set environment variables in your current shell), and neither will `(...)`, since all the assignments in the parentheses only effect that subshell.`foo=3; (foo=5); echo "$foo"` will output 3, not 5.

Comment: @chepner not exactly. I can't call `source file` from the terminal and expect the same results. Because that never worked. The only time I get the same results is when I create a sub shell explicitly, whether via the terminal, or from the script. I can however use `bash` instead of `source` to execute the script, and get the same results, but only when I execute my script in a sub shell explicitly

Comment: @chepner by install stuff, I actually mean create a virtual environment, activate that virtual environment, and then execute `pip install -r $apath/requirements.txt`within that activated environment. It's why I used source in the first place to call the script

Comment: It works *both* if i try to execute my script directly (`./my_script.sh`) and via source `source ./my_script.sh`. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Simply source the file with a failsafe:

```
source the-source-file || true
```

... then the overall command won't fail, even if `source` does.

Comment: Actually, I thought this was what I wanted, but turns out my terminal was just being slow... I actually want to return to the terminal on error, (meaning stop the entire script in it's tracks).. .for whatever reason, `source file || true`  doesn't do this, neither does `source file || return`  when I type this into the terminal...

Comment: Sourcing the file doesn't return you to a shell prompt??

Comment: this is what's in my terminal: `Jills-MBP:~ jillr$ source ~/Desktop/site_builder/create.sh blah || true` It simply executes the next part of the script on fail, so does return instead of true. The only thing that has worked is `command || return` statements in the actual file for all commands, which is silly. I don't know if throwing it all in a function then calling `function || return` at the end of the file would do any good either.

Comment: Well, if you explicitly put `|| return` on a command that fails, the yes, it'll return. I thought we were trying to keep your main/parent shell from exiting?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the terminal from actually exiting. Because I don't want to exit the terminal. I want to exit the script. Return on individual commands in the script exits the script and leaves my terminal in the same condition as pressing Ctrl+C to kill a process, such as running the server form the terminal,  would. I want to avoid writing command || return for every line in the file :D

Comment: So would it be as simple as unsetting errexit in script?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I've already removed `set -o errexit` from the top of the script, if that's what you're talking about... I don't understand why `source file argument || return` wouldn't just work in the terminal... it's not though

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `set -o errexit`, you can use `trap`:

```
trap 'trap - ERR RETURN; kill -INT $$ ; return' ERR RETURN
```

`kill -INT $$` acts like `exit`, but if the script was sourced it does nothing (and the `return` runs instead)
(I believe this works because the input prompt catches the signal, preventing the shell from exiting)

`trap - ...` disables the traps so they don't run after the script exits

Answer (score 1):

As a simple workaround, you could run a shell in your current shell and source there. Something like:

1. Open a new terminal and set everything up the way you want it. You mentioned some environment variables and the like. Set them up here.
2. In that terminal, start a new shell. For instance, `bash`.
3. Do your thing. Source your script. If it exits, you're just thrown into the first shell and everything is still set up. Just run `bash` again and you're back in business.

To illustrate, I created this script which will fail if you try to source it:

```
$ cat /home/terdon/scripts/bar.sh
set -o errexit
var='bar
```

Let's see what happens if I start a nested shell session and then source it (note that I am using the portable name for the `source` command, `.`; `source` is a bashism):

```
parent-shell $ bash      ## start a new shell
child-shell $ . ~/scripts/bar.sh
bash: /home/terdon/scripts/bar.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
parent-shell $
```

As you can see, the syntax error caused the sourced script to exit which, in turn caused my shell session to exit but since it was a nested session, that just landed me back at the original, parent shell with all the variables still set up. Now, just run a new shell again and you can go back to sourcing your script.

Comment: I'm going to try this really quick

Comment: This has the intended effect... the downside is that the variables I create for the parent shell, aren't accessible in the child shell, which contains one of the variables I need for execution in the child shell. Is there a way to spawn a subshell from the file I'm executing? That way, I can still call the script in the parent shell, and  can still access the variables I need to? I'm literally setting `create_path=~/Desktop/site_builder/create.sh`  in the parent shell because I do it so often. And I need it to call source $create_path [argument] to execute the script.

Comment: @JillRussek if the variables are not being passed to the child shell, you're not `export`ing them. But what you describe really makes very little sense. It is sounding more and more like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). You might want to post a new question explaining what your end objective is. I bet we can give you a better solution that all this weird sourcing.

Comment: Hmm. I might give that a shot too. Right now, just spawning the child shell from the script instead of from the terminal is doing exactly what I want it to. I have to source the script from the terminal in order to create a virtual environment in the script, and pip install stuff in it. It's working as intended now.

Comment: But you're right, I wasn't exporting the variables, because I didn't know I needed to :D. (I've never spawned a child shell before)